error: casting `&mut i32` as `usize` is invalid
I have a code that counts number of elements in vector that contains only 0, 1, 2 values
    pub fn sort_colors(nums: &mut Vec<i32>) {
        let mut cntColors = vec![0; 3];
        
        for num in nums {
            cntColors[(num) as usize] += 1; // ERROR: casting `&mut i32` as `usize` is invalid
        }

I fixed the error with help of this code
        for idx in 0..nums.len() {
            cntColors[nums[idx] as usize] += 1;
        }

What is the proper way to cast &mut i32 to usize?

Have you tried dereferencing before casting?

So if you attempt to compile your code, you get this error message from the compiler:
error[E0606]: casting `&mut i32` as `usize` is invalid
 --> src\main.rs:7:19
  |
7 |         cntColors[(num) as usize] += 1;
  |                   ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  |
help: dereference the expression
  |
7 |         cntColors[*(num) as usize] += 1;
  |                   +

So, if we do as the compiler suggests and insert a * before num, we get
pub fn sort_colors(nums: &mut Vec<i32>) {
    let mut cntColors = vec![0; 3];
    
    for num in nums {
        cntColors[*num as usize] += 1;
    }

}

Which works just fine.  The main lesson here is to actually read the messages you get from the compiler, but I will also provide a more detailed explanation for what's going on here.
Since nums has type &mut Vec<i32>, that is, a mutable reference to a vector of i32s.  When we use it in a for loop, the elements we see are themselves references to the elements of the vector.  They have type &mut i32.  So, in order to use this to index another sequence, we want a usize.  So step one is to dereference the &mut i32 into an i32 using the dereference operator *, then we can cast this into usize using as.  So if num has type &mut i32, then *num as type i32, and *num as usize has type usize.
Another way to solve this is to do this:
pub fn sort_colors(nums: &mut Vec<i32>) {
    let mut cntColors = vec![0; 3];
    
    for &mut num in nums {
        cntColors[num as usize] += 1;
    }

}

This uses a pattern binding to destructure the &mut i32 so that num actually refers to the i32 behind the reference instead of the reference itself.

It may be worth elaborating that for ... in obtains an iterator from IntoIterator::into_iter, which in the case of &mut Vec<i32> yields slice::IterMut<i32> and hence items of type &mut i32.
